# How to use grep command to achieve this?

Tags: linux, grep

I have several files `file_1, file_2, ..` inside a folder and some files contain a pattern `pattern_abc`.

How can I make a new_file which contains the lines from all the files having the pattern `pattern_abc`?

Comment: Having pattern `pattern_abc` in their files name or in content? if name, then just do `cat *pattern_abc* >>new_fike`

Comment: As you can see from the answers so far, there is some confusion about whether you want _only the matching lines from all files_ or _the complete contents of any file matching the pattern_.  Could you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 2):

To pick only the lines that match `pattern_abc` from all files in `dir`, use

```
$ grep -h 'pattern_abc' dir/* > new_file
```

The `-h` flag will cause `grep` to not output the filename together with the matching lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursive grep,

```
grep -r pattern directory > new_file
```

- `-r` Read all files under each directory,  recursively.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -lZ pattern_abc folder/file_* | xargs -r0 cat > new_file
```

(If using `zsh`, you can replace `file_*` with `file_*(.)` to only consider *regular* files, or `file_*(.n)` to sort the list of files *numerically* (so `file_9` comes *before* `file_10` for instance).

Or recursively and only considering *regular* files:

```
find folder -name 'file_*' -type f -exec grep -lZ pattern_abc {} +|
  xargs -r0 cat > new_file
```

Note however that the list of files is not sorted, so the files will be concatenated in some random order.

With `zsh` to sort the files numerically within each folder they're found:

```
grep -lZ pattern_abc folder/**/file_*(Dn.) | xargs -r0 cat > new_file
```

(`D` to also look inside hidden directories like `find` does).

Answer (score 0):

This will find the files that contain lines matching `pattern_abc`, and output their contents in full (not just the matching lines).

`grep -q`, stops as soon as first matched pattern found and `find` processes the next file.

```
find . -type f -execdir grep -q 'pattern_abc' {} \; -exec cat {} >> /path/to/outfile \;
```

Comment: As a side note, you have `-exec cat {} >> outfile \;`, with the redirection seemingly inside the `-exec` command line. The redirection actually takes effect for the whole of `find` (it doesn't matter where in the command line the redirection is). It works just fine here, since `cat` should be the only thing that prints any output, but if multiple parts of the `find` would produce output, you'd need to do something different.